# regex encapsulation php

Tags: php, regex

What are the differences pros/cons of using either '/' or '#' as the regex encapsulation

e.g.

```
'/' = preg_match('/MYSEARCH}(.+)ENDMYSEARCH/s',$out,$matches);

'#' = preg_match('#MYSEARCH}(.+)ENDMYSEARCH#s',$out,$matches);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only thing that matters to PHP / PCRE is that you must use the **same character at the beginning and at the end**.

What matters to you is escaping : inside the regex, you have to escape the delimiter if you want to use it.

For instance, to match a part of an URL, using / as a delimiter, you regex might look like this :

```
'/^http:\/\/www/'
```

Using `/` as delimiter, you have to escape the slashes which are inside the regex -- not easy, and not looking well.

On the other hand, using `#` as delimiter :

```
'#http://www#'
```

Much more easier to write and read, isn't it ?

Depeding on your need and/or preference, you can use whatever character you want -- I sometimes see '`!`' or '`~`', for instance.

Comment: Wasn't aware you could use a character of your preference, and I thought I had learned what was to be learned of PHP Regexs.

Comment: @Lizard : you're welcome :-) ;; @MitMaro : there is always more than what you think, with PCRE ;-)

Comment: Personally I use backtick ` It's rarely used inside my regexps.

Answer (score 1):

Also remember that with [preg_quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) you can add the delimiter to be escaped.